# How to prepend Maybe lists to lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function like the one provided below:

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> Maybe [(a,b)]
zip (headX:tailX) (headY:tailY) = (headX,headY):zip tailX tailY
zip _ _ = Nothing
```

Now

```
zip tailX tailY
```

Will return a type of Maybe list, and I am trying to prepend (headX,headY) to it using the : operator. Is there an easy way to do this? If I try to prepend it directly the compiler gives me errors because : operator only works on lists.

Comment: Do you want `zip (1:2:[]) (3:[])` to be `(1,3):Nothing`? Because that's what you wrote, but it's not a valid `Maybe [(a,b)]`. Can you figure out what you want the answer to be?

Comment: What exactly is this version of `zip` supposed to do? Only zip lists of the same length?

Comment: Remember, `Maybe` is a functor. Regular `zip` applies the partially applied function `(:) (headX, headY)` to the recursive result. What can you do to apply the same function to a `Maybe [(a, b)]` instead? (Also, consider how you will distinguish between exactly one empty-list argument and *both*  arguments empty.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use `fmap` to convert your prepending-to-a-list operation to a prepending-to-every-list-in-a-container-of-lists operation.

```
zip (headX:tailX) (headY:tailY) = fmap ((headX,headY):) (zip tailX tailY)
```

Sometimes it's more clear to use the infix version of `fmap`.

```
zip (headX:tailX) (headY:tailY) = ((headX,headY):) <$> zip tailX tailY
```

I don't have a strong preference in this case; let your heart guide you.

Comment: Note the `zip _ _ = Nothing` base case, though, which makes `fmap` trivial. I'm unsure about what the OP really wants.

Answer (score 2):

`Maybe []` is not `[]`. You cannot use `:` directly.

But you can define a function to do it for you, using pattern matching to get to the list contained within (if there *is* a list).

```
mycons :: a -> Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a]
mycons _ Nothing = Nothing
mycons v (Just lst) = Just (v:lst)
```

Now:

```
mycons 1 $ mycons 2 $ mycons 3 $ Just []
-- Just [1,2,3]

mycons 1 $ mycons 2 $ mycons 3 $ Nothing
-- Nothing
```